# How to SET dynamic property within a foreach?

Tags: neo4j

I have been setting dynamic properties successfully using apoc, but getting stuck not able to use apoc within a foreach..

Equivalent of what I'd like to do:

```
   MATCH (n:Label {id: {id}})
   MERGE (n)-[rel:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(UniqueNode:UniqueLabel)
   WITH DISTINCT rel, ["DynamicProp1", "DynamicProp2", "DynamicProp3", "LongListWouldRatherNotDoOneAtATime"] as list
   FOREACH (x in list | 
            FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(rel[x]) THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
                SET rel[x]=false))
```

Since can't use SET rel[x]=false would have to use

```
CALL apoc.create.setRelProperty(rel, x, false)
```

But wont' let me use it in a foreach...
Is there a way to do this? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNWIND to get a row per element in the list, filter for if the key doesn't exist, then use APOC to set it.

```
MATCH (n:Label {id: {id}})
MERGE (n)-[rel:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(UniqueNode:UniqueLabel)
WITH rel
UNWIND ["DynamicProp1", "DynamicProp2", "DynamicProp3", "LongListWouldRatherNotDoOneAtATime"] as propKey
WITH rel, propKey
WHERE NOT EXISTS(rel[propKey])
CALL apoc.create.setRelProperty(rel, propKey, false)
RETURN count(*)
```

Comment: Beautiful , thanks. I wish I could keep my starting node(s) but I guess maybe that's for the next version...

Comment: You can keep `n` and `UniqueNode` in scope, just include them in your WITH clauses.